# Terraform modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

Sorry folks it might be a silly question, I am new to terraform modules. I have created 2 private registries which are S3 and common tags. So whenever I am deploying S3 using the S3 module, How can I call the private shared tag module to get the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using modules, you get the output like this:

```
module "commontags" {
  source = "path"
  ...
}

module "s3module" {
  tags = module.commontags.tags
}
```

Check the [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) to get more examples.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am slightly confused, I don't wanna get the output instead I want the S3 module to call the common tags module to get the tags and those tags should get added to the new S3 bucket. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Why not get the output from the common tags module and then pass the output of that module to the S3 module as variables? I have updated my answer.

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct :)